# Tengo error de incompatible types java.lang.object

Tags: java

Es un programa con listas y conexiones uno a muchos y tengo un error de tipo incompatible `types java.lang.object`.

Pongo la clase `Cliente` que es la llamada en la clase `Almacén` que a la vez es donde se marca el error.

**Clase Cliente**

```
package supermercado;

import java.util.Objects;

/**
 *
 * @author sdh
 */
public class Cliente extends Persona { //Herencia de Persona

    /*Atributos*/
    private Long telefono;
    private String correo;
    private int puntos;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param telefono
     * @param correo
     * @param puntos
     * @param identificacion
     * @param nombre
     * @param apellidos
     * @param genero
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public Cliente(Long telefono, String correo, int puntos, long identificacion, String nombre, String apellidos, Genero genero) throws Exception {
        super(identificacion, nombre, apellidos, genero);
        
        String telefonoString = Long.toString(telefono);
        if (!(telefonoString.length() == 10)) {
            throw new Exception("El telefono solo puede tener 10 digitos");
        }
        if ((correo == null) || (correo.trim().equals(""))) {
            throw new Exception("El correo NO puede ser NULL o VACIO");
        }
        if (!(puntos > 0)) {
            throw new Exception("Los puntos NO pueden DIFERENTES a MAYOR de 0");
        }

        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.correo = correo;
        this.puntos = puntos;
    }

    /*Metodos Get.*/
    public Long getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return correo;
    }

    public int getPuntos() {
        return puntos;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Cliente other = (Cliente) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(super.getIdentificacion(), other.getIdentificacion())) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    
}
```

Clase `Almacén` donde está el error de `object`. Para ser más exacto en el método **buscar cliente** en la parte interna del `for`.

```
package supermercado;

import java.util.LinkedList;

/**
 *
 * @author sdh
 */
public class Almacen {

    //Asociacion uno a muchos
    private LinkedList<Empleado> empleados;
    private LinkedList<Producto> productos;
    private LinkedList<TipoProducto> tipoProductos;
    private LinkedList<Cliente> clientes;

    /*Atributos*/
    private long nit;
    private String nombre;
    private String direccion;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param nit
     * @param nombre
     * @param direccion
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    public Almacen(long nit, String nombre, String direccion) throws Exception {
        if (!(nit == 1000000000L && nit == 9000000000L)) {
            throw new Exception("El nit solo puede tener 10 digitos");
        }
        if (nombre == null || nombre.trim().equals("")) {
            throw new Exception("El nombre NO puede ser NULL o VACIO");
        }
        if (direccion == null || direccion.trim().equals("")) {
            throw new Exception("La direccion NO puede ser NULL o VACIO");
        }

        this.empleados = new LinkedList<>();
        this.productos = new LinkedList<>();
        this.tipoProductos = new LinkedList<>();
        this.clientes = new LinkedList<>();
        this.nit = nit;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    /*Metodos Get.*/
    public LinkedList<Empleado> getEmpleados() {
        return empleados;
    }

    public LinkedList<Producto> getProductos() {
        return productos;
    }

    public LinkedList<TipoProducto> getTipoProductos() {
        return tipoProductos;
    }

    public LinkedList<Cliente> getClientes() {
        return clientes;
    }

    public long getNit() {
        return nit;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    //Metodos recomendados
    /**
     * Agregar Cliente
     *
     * @param Nuevocliente
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void agregarCliente(Cliente Nuevocliente) throws Exception {
        if (this.clientes.contains(Nuevocliente)) {
            throw new Exception("El cliente ya se encuentra registrado");
        }
        this.clientes.add(Nuevocliente);
    }

    /**
     * Buscar cliente
     * 
     * @param identificacion
     * @return
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public Cliente Bcliente(long identificacion) throws Exception {
        for (Cliente c : clientes) {
            if (c.getIdentificacion() == identificacion) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("El cliente NO se ha encontrado");
    }

    /**
     * Agregar empleado
     *
     * @param NuevoEmpleado
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void agregarEmpleado(Empleado NuevoEmpleado) throws Exception {
        if (this.empleados.contains(NuevoEmpleado)) {
            throw new Exception("El empleado ya existe");
        }
        this.empleados.add(NuevoEmpleado);
    }

}
```

El error se marca en el método **buscar cliente** al hacer el llamado de la conexión de clases como lista de linkedlist de la clase `Cliente`.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por tu descripción, el código parece correcto; si el error está en la línea `for (Cliente c: clientes) {` (*) lo que pasa es que estás metiendo en `clientes` alguna instancia de Object y no de Cliente.. pero no veo en el código que estés haciendo nada de esto. Intenta agregar **exactamente** el mensaje de la excepción (y el stacktrace) e indicar (mediante un comentario en el código) la línea que falla.

Answer (score 0):

El error esta aca

```
if (c.getIdentificacion() == identificacion)
```

Segun yo estas intentando comparar un tipo objeto Long con un tipo primitivo long , podrias resolverlo cambiando el tipo del parametro identificacion por el tipo envoltorio Long y compararlos usando equals .